# I know you'll solve this

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

> My prefix will make you afraid
> My infix will make it cliched
> My suffix is the end of a chime
> My whole is ahead of its time

Hint:

> The title is part of the puzzle

Comment: Uh, futuristic? I don't know how you do the first one though

Comment: Postmodern. making it from the last clue

Comment: confident! is that it?

Comment: @zixuan Please look up previous affix riddles to get an idea of how they work. You not only need the word itself but to figure out how the prefix, infix and suffix also fit your word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Credit to @Smartest1here for re-interpreting my original answer into something that fit a little better!*

Are you

> `FORETELLING`

My prefix will make you afraid

> `FORE`! shouts someone at a golf course. Look out!

My infix will make it cliched

> `RETELL` I'm real tired of seeing the same stories being retold over and over again.

My postfix is the end of a chime

> `LING` can be found at the end of a DING-A-LING

My whole is ahead of its time

> To foretell something is to guess that it will occur before it does.

According to the hint...

> You have foretold in the title that an answer would be found!

Comment: Damn I did not know fore was a warning.

Comment: It could also be foretelling

Comment: @Smartest1here You are probably correct. Would you like to make your own post, or allow me to post the in-betweens with credit to you for the final?

Comment: @Smartest1here I could also do a community wiki answer if you'd prefer?

Comment: No need you worked out the most of this riddle. You deserve the credit 

Comment: @Smartest1here I appreciate it, thank you. Good find!

Comment: Well done  that was the intended answer. I hope you liked the riddle 

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer might be

> Anticipating

My prefix will make you afraid

> [Antic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antic) has a definition "grotesque or bizarre" which could certainly imply fear-inducing.

My infix will make it cliched

> [Pat](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pat) is an adjective which can mean "learned, mastered, or memorized exactly" which would certainly make anything cliche.

My postfix is the end of a chime

> [Ting](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ting) is a sharp, clear ringing sound, such as that made when a glass is struck by a metal object which, I would say characterises the tail end of a chime also.

My whole is ahead of its time

> Anticipating means giving advance thought, discussion, or treatment to.

Title

> The OP is "anticipating" that we will solve this riddle.

Comment: This is a great answer, but not the intended one. The intended word has no resemblance to this one, but their meanings are definitely related.

Comment: @CG. Okay, no problem, just to clarify, are all my affixes wrong?

Comment: Yes, every affix is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word is:

> Counterdemanding

My prefix will make you afraid:

> When playing a game with a time limit, you can get scared/nervous

My infix will make it cliched:

> When referring to someone, often people use "man", even though that person might be a woman. "hey man!" is a cliche greeting.

My postfix is the end of a chime:

> Chimes can end with "Ding!"

My whole is ahead of it's time:

> Often someone's boss can counterdemand some things ahead of time. For instance, "In two days the client will send a report, please finish it".

The hint in the question:

> You were counterdemanding an answer!