# Ra Really really rard Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

Here's another one:

> My prefix is Harry's son,
> My suffix exchanged with o is a relative.
> My infix is just two letters,
> But reversed an example.
> My whole is a topic,
> which I really like (and everybody who read my profile knows it.)

Comment: Of course, is it MATHEMATICS?

Comment: well, maybe....

Comment: Huh? What do you mean?

Comment: @zixuan can you please post substantiated answers, in spoiler form, instead of guessing in [comments](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105776/i-know-youll-solve-this/105804#comment298813_105776)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are

> Algebra

My prefix is Harry's son,

> Al is short for Albus, one of Harry Potter's sons.

My suffix exchanged with o is a relative.

> Bra can be turned into Bro which is short for Brother, a relative.

My infix is just two letters,
But reversed an example.

> Ge reversed is e.g. which means for example.

My whole is a topic, which I really like (and everybody who read my profile knows it.)

> Since you like math, I think you would like Algebra.

Comment: Right answer. Keep it up.