# Murder mystery of Dirk

Tags: situation, mystery

Once I was spying, just for fun, on a classmate at a shopping mall. He (Jack) was meeting his friend (Dirk).

> Jack (speaking to himself and holding some bubble gum): I'm not going to buy those. They look nice but they are too costly.
> Dirk: Hi Jack!
> Jack: I'm going to buy those. They are too nice. Hi Dirk!
> Dirk: You wanted to show me these bubble gum, right?
> Jack: Many many murders are happening here. So let's stay cool and eat some bubble gum.
> Dirk: Yes, you're right.

I went straight to the police and I was right. Dirk was lying dead. He wanted to give Dirk one more chance, since he is his best friend.

How did I know that Jack wanted to murder Dirk?

Comment: @zixuan Sorry, no. It would be too obvious.

Comment: @zixuan, you have been [told](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105830/ra-really-really-rard-riley-riddle#comment299003_105830) [twice](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105776/i-know-youll-solve-this#comment298826_105776) now to **stop making guesses in comments**. If you think you have an answer supported by the information in the puzzle, **post it as an answer**.

Comment: Can we have a hint?

Comment: Well yes:  Look at more what Jack said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess:

> I would think that the fact 1) The things that he wanted to buy was a lethal weapon or potentially could be one (set of knives because of the price) 2) Jack was initally apprehensive to buy the object but then changed his mind when he saw his friend meaning that something about his friend made him buy the object 3) You probably had knowledge that there has been murders recently using those kinds of untensils, he maybe wanted to by new weapons because those weapons were found disposed. 4) The Bubble gum was already bought beforehand and was not what he was wanting to buy.

Comment: Right answer with all 4 clues.

Answer (score -4):

Jack: I am going to buy those things. They are too nice. Hi Dirk! He does not tell what he is buying but admits they are too nice things. I think he murdered his friend with one of these too nice things. Jack and Dirk both eat bubble gum.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Why does this conversation occur? How does that support your answer? What is your specific answer to "How did I know that Jack wanted to murder Dirk?"

Comment: Jack  used  some of these too nice things to murder  his friend. What these nice things are, he's not telling us. But the person watching him knew.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis Nice answer, your almost there.